# Reduce space between FluidRow

Tags: r, layout, shiny, shinydashboard

I'am trying to create a specific layout in shiny and I'am stuck to reduce space between tab1 and tab5 :
[image]

This code below shows a couple of things that I have tried :

```
body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      height = "300px",
      tabPanel("tab1")
    ),
    tabBox(
      height = "600px",
      tabPanel("tab2"),
      tabPanel("tab3"),
      tabPanel("tab4")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      height = "300px",
      tabPanel("tab5")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "example"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    body
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    
  }
)
```

Some help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this.  Please see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fluidPage.html) for more details on `fillRow()` and `fillCol()`.

```
ui <- fillPage(
  fillRow( #flex=c(1,1),
    fillCol(
      div(shinydashboard::tabBox(
        height = "300px", width="100%",
        tabPanel("tab1", plotOutput("plotTopLeft", height = "300px"))
      )),
      div(shinydashboard::tabBox(
        height = "300px", width="100%",
        tabPanel("tab5", plotOutput("plotBottomLeft", height = "300px"))
      ))
    ),
    fillCol(
      shinydashboard::tabBox(
        height = "600px", width="100%",
        tabPanel("tab2", plotOutput("plotRight", height = "550px")),
        tabPanel("tab3"),
        tabPanel("tab4")
      )
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plotTopLeft <- renderPlot(plot(cars))
  output$plotRight <- renderPlot(plot(pressure))
  output$plotBottomLeft <- renderPlot(plot(AirPassengers))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]